# Split a number vector into different thunks with continuous numbers

Tags: r, split, tidyverse

Given a vector as `c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)`, how to split it into different trunks with the continuous ones as a cluster, the desired result is `c(1)`, `c(3,4,5)`, `c(7,8,9,10)`?

rules:split the numbers into different clusters; each cluster only include continuous ordered numbers.

The clusters and how many numbers in each cluster are issued as followed, but how to split and get the result with ***trunks***? or other methods? Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

num <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)

num_seq <- seq(min(num), max(num))

chunks <- num_seq %in% num %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  paste(collapse = " ") %>% 
  str_split("FALSE") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  map(.f = ~str_count(., "TRUE"))

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

Comment: Please specify the rules to partition the numbers into their corresponding chunks.

Answer (score 4):

A `base` solution: You can use `diff()`+`cumsum()` to determine where the sequence is consecutive.

```r
num <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)

split(num, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(num) != 1)))

# $`1`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# $`3`
# [1]  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: This meets the best answer with base code!!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This `data.table` solution works, but it is generally not as fast as Darren's base `split` solution:

```
library(data.table)
num <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)
data.table(num)[, .(chunks = .(num)), cumsum(num - shift(num, fill = -Inf) > 1)]$chunks
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Quite helpful for me.